# Too localised? Building Wireless Drivers for X

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic

This post has received a vote to be closed because it is too localised: [Building Wireless Drivers for Edimax Wireless USB: EW-7811UN](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14/building-wireless-drivers-for-edimax-wireless-usb-ew-7811un)

Is it too localised or should we be encouraging such a post?

Comment: I'm not sure how this was considered localised. It's already been confirmed that someone else is using the same device.

Answer (score 1):

## No

**We should encourage this type of post,** as we can provide focused walkthroughs that may be applicable to other types of peripheral.